# proper way to set android phone background

Tags: android, json, background, wallpaper

I have this codes to get Bing's photo of the day and set it as background.it works fine but I have some feelings that It's not the best way.

get json and return string :

```
private String GetHTTPData() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            stream = sb.toString();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } else {
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stream);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                imageURL = "http://www.bing.com" + jsonobject.getString("url");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //I replaced the original resolution with mine to change the image url
    imageURL=imageURL.replace("1920x1080","1080x1920");
    return imageURL;
}
```

default value for image is 1920x1080 and I was able to get more phone friendly image by replacing dimensions, but I'm not sure if 1080x1920 is the best one.

and then my `AsyncTask`

```
    private class setWallpaper extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... strings) {
        int response=-1;

        InputStream in=null;
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        String stream=GetHTTPData();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stream);
            URLConnection connection =url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)connection;
            urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            response=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            }
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            in.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        //I dont like to scale my bitmap but on lower resolution i cant get full width image
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        Bitmap bitmapTouse=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,width,height,true);
        bitmap.recycle();

        return bitmapTouse;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        System.gc();
        WallpaperManager manager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d("SUCCESS----", "Finished");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("FAILED----",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I also don't like to scale my bitmap image but I had to.

Comment: can u put your xml ..! and this is for ur app background or your device wallpaper